# Java Function Overloading

Tags: java

Can anyone tell me, why does "int" gets printed, as in the internal working.

```
class Test {

void Method(int i) {
    System.out.println("int");
}
void Method(String n) {
    System.out.println("string");
}

public static void main(String [] a) {
    new Test().Method('c');
    }

}
```

Comment: the char is being cast to int.  Put double quotes and you will get string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The character `c` is being cast to an `int`.  It *isn't* going to be cast to a `String`.

More formally, from [the JLS §5.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5) - a widening conversion takes place from a `char` to an `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`.

The reason that will never be seen as a `String` is that a `char` can't be autoboxed into a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

`'c'` is a character as per its single quotes. Being a primitive, numeric(somewhat) type, it's cast to an integer more readily than a string as the latter must be explicit.

You can also modify `Method(int i)` to print `i` and try different characters.

Answer (score 1):

The `char` is actually a numeric type in `Java`. It is automacally transformed to `int` when you make the callback, that's why the method prints `int`.

From the [Oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), we can read that:

> The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has
>   a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or
>   65,535 inclusive).

Answer (score 1):

Passing a variable with single quotes is considered to be a `char`. Characters become converted to `int` variables.

If you want to pass it as a `String` simply use double quotes.

```
new Test().Method("c");
```

specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:

> byte to short, int, long, float, or double
>
> short to int, long, float, or double
>
> **char to int, long, float, or double**
>
> int to long, float, or double
>
> long to float or double
>
> float to double

You can read more here: [JLS §5.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

`char` is a **primitive type** and its being casted to `int`, whilst the `String` is an **object**.

On the other hand, there is a feature in java called *autoboxing* where some primitive types are casted to objects when suited (e.g. `int` to `Integer`, `boolean` to `Boolean`) but it does not work for `char`. `char` gets autoboxed to `Character`.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `'c'` it is assumed to be a `char`; if you try to pass `"c"`, it will be assumed as a `string`.

Comment: nope i meant 'c' is char and is assumed as an int so the int version of overloaded function is called

Comment: I'm just trying to tell you to be thorough with your answer. Don't let anyone assume anything.

Comment: i dont want somebody to assume, with 'assume' i mean assumed by compiler, not anyone :)

Answer (score 0):

'c' is a char type not a string. 'c' may be compare to (int)'c'

Answer (score 0):

In Java, characters are represented as numbers. Specifically, Java represents a character by its Unicode codepoint. If I'm not mistaken, the character 'c' is number 98 in the Unicode specification.

When you call `Method('c')`, the program has two method signature options: one where 'c' is an `int`, another where it is a `String`. Since, deep down, 'c' is a number, it is cast to `int` and treated as the number 98. Characters are not cast to `Strings`.